# Was program opened by a user or was it started from windows registry start up?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, startup

Is it somehow possible to detect whether program was started by a user or it was started automatically from registry at Windows start up?

Comment: I can't see what's the point either ways the program is running but you can check the startup in the registery and if the program is there it can be considered to be running at the startup.

Comment: The difference is that if it is automatically started from registry, I want to hide the main window by default, if not not, then show.

Comment: @A_Nablsi: Only problem there is, running from Startup and running from...say...a desktop shortcut would still look alike.  A program doesn't usually remove itself from startup once it's done its startup stuff.  So instead of always looking like the user started it, it'll always look like Windows did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way i know of would be to add a "--startup" or similar option to the command line for the startup shortcut (or the value in Run), and check for that in your app.  If it's there, then the app is being run by Windows; otherwise, the user is running it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args[1] == "-hide")
{
//Hide
}
```